# How do I create a newcommand which outputs a letter with an index?

Tags: macros, math-operators

When I use

```
\newcommand{\F1}{$\mathrm{F}_1$}
```

I get the `Missing \begin{document}.` error and `missing $ inserted` if I move it inside the document.

How do I define a macro so that `\F1` would expand to `$\mathrm{F}_1$`?

I can do

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\F1}{F_1}
```

but then I have to use it as `$\F1$` instead of just `\F1`.

Comment: As a general rule, macros can't have numbers in them.  (Also, welcome to TeX.SX!)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: no, this is a different issue!

Comment: Try defining it like `\newcommand\F[1]{$\mathrm{F}_#1$}`.  That will define a small macro `\F` that looks at the next 'token' at puts it as the subscript. (Keep in mind that one-letter macros are generally bad to make)

Comment: @sds: Defining `\H0`, `\H1`, ... looks pretty close to `\F1`, doesn't it?

Comment: @sds Unfortunately, it's *not* a different issue.  Use something similar to the command definition I posted above if you want this kind of functionality.  (Reading the TeXbook or TeX by Topic would be good reading for you concerning this.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: yes, sorry, this is, indeed, a dupe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write `\newcommand{\F}[1]{$\mathrm{F}_{#1}$}`. This defines a macro which takes a single argument. You can then write `\F1`, which will expand to `$\mathrm{F}_{1}$`,
`\F2` which will expand to `$\mathrm{F}_{2}$`, etc. This form will work for any one letter argument, but you can also write `\F{i,j}` as short hand for `$\mathrm{F}_{i,j}$`.

Comment: Please, please, *please* use something more descriptive than `\F` in your actual document, though!

Comment: What can be more descriptive to the letter 'F' than the macro `\F`? ;-)

Comment: @SeanAllred: [F1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) is quite idiomatic.

Comment: @sds seems like `\newcommand*\Fscore{\mathrm{F}_1}` would be a good definition (the macro doesn't describe the letter F but a mathematical function). Also since it is most likely to be used in math-mode the definition should not contain `$`. `$\Fscore=\frac{...}{...}$`

Comment: @srs That may be, but consider the shortcut I see all-too-often: `\let\>\geq`.  One-letter (or excessively short) macro names are almost *always* used elsewhere.  Redefine it and you risk breaking things in *very* bad, *very* unexpected ways.